# wget -P -O together does not work?

Tags: wget

i did try command:

```
#!/bin/bash
folder_tmp=~/name-x-tmp/   #this is worked
echo -n "url: " && read -e url   #this is worked
wget -P $folder_tmp -O 1.txt $url  #this is not worked!!
exit 1
```

what is my wrong?
maybe is not worked toghter -P and -O, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not explicitly stated in the man page but `-O` effectively preempts everything else in terms of the path to the output file.  To achieve what you want try

```
mkdir -p "$folder_tmp"
wget -O "$folder_tmp/1.txt" "$url"
```

Comment: Be sure to quote your variables!

Comment: Fixed.  It was a quick copy/paste job and I didn't proof it well enough ;)  Thanks for catching it

Comment: > out error:   /home/user/name-x-tmp//1.txt: File o directory did not existent

Comment: Does the directory `/home/user/name-x-temp` exist?  You'll need to make sure the directory exists first.

Comment: instead with -P will create automatic if directory not exist..

Comment: Try my edited code

Comment: ok mkdir is add command, but it's impossible toghter -O and -P, right?

Comment: The man page doesn't state that explicitly but it does imply that `-O` behaves that way, yes.